# python ctypes unexpected behavior on windows

Tags: python, ctypes

```
import ctypes
print(ctypes.c_int32)
```

on linux (and os x) this code returns <class 'ctypes.c_int32'>
on windows returns <class 'ctypes.c_long'>

Why this happen and how to fix this? I just want to work software on windows in the same way as it works on Linux.

**update**

There is custom a class

```
class ctype:
    ....
    ctype.int32 = _make_ctype_from_ctypes(ctypes.c_int32)
    ....
```

with this function:

```
def _make_ctype_from_ctypes(ctypes_type):
    ctypes_namespace = dict(ctypes_type.__dict__)

    namespace = {
        "__module__": _Numeric.__module__,
        "_type_": ctypes_namespace["_type_"],
    }

    return type(
        ctypes_type.__name__.replace("c_", ""),
        tuple([_Numeric, *ctypes_type.__bases__]),
        namespace,
    )
```

error happens here:

```
class _Numeric:
    _type_: str

    def __init__(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, (bytearray, bytes)):
            value = struct.unpack(self._type_, value)[0]
        if isinstance(value, _Numeric):
            value = value.value
        if "int" in self.__class__.__name__:
            value = int(value)
        super().__init__(value) <-------------
```

stacktrace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wotori\git\L2py\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(clock.ticks)
  File "C:\Users\wotori\git\L2py\game\game\models\world.py", line 40, in ticks
    return ctype.int(int(time.time() - self.start_time) / self.MSEC_IN_TICK)
  File "C:\Users\wotori\git\L2py\common\common\ctype.py", line 19, in __init__
    super().__init__(value)
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I tried to add exception handler to the line where the problem happen so we able to see with which exacly numbers the error happen but it doesn't make any sense for me:

```
try:
    super().__init__(value)
except Exception as e:
    print("error", e, value)
```

the output on error:

```
error 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer 1639347702.44
error 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer 0.0
```

little reminder, this code works on linux and osx but not on windows.

**UPDATE #2**
Minimal example.
This code run on linux with no error but fail on windows.
The same 64 bit python installed on both computers.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from dataclasses import dataclass, field
    import time


    @dataclass(kw_only=True)
    class Clock:
        start_time: int = field(default=int(time.time()))
        _is_night = False
        TICKS_PER_SECOND = 10
        MSEC_IN_TICK = 1000 / TICKS_PER_SECOND

        @property
        def is_night(self):
            return self.hours < 6

        @property
        def hours(self):
            return (self.get_time() / 60) % 24

        @property
        def ticks(self):
            return ctype.int(int(time.time() - self.start_time) / self.MSEC_IN_TICK)

        def get_time(self):
            return ctype.int32(self.ticks / (self.TICKS_PER_SECOND * 10))


    import struct


    class _Numeric:
        _type_: str

        def __init__(self, value):
            if isinstance(value, (bytearray, bytes)):
                value = struct.unpack(self._type_, value)[0]
            if isinstance(value, _Numeric):
                value = value.value
            if "int" in self.__class__.__name__:
                value = int(value)
            super().__init__(value)


    def _make_ctype_from_ctypes(ctypes_type):
        ctypes_namespace = dict(ctypes_type.__dict__)

        namespace = {
            "__module__": _Numeric.__module__,
            "_type_": ctypes_namespace["_type_"],
        }

        return type(
            ctypes_type.__name__.replace("c_", ""),
            tuple([_Numeric, *ctypes_type.__bases__]),
            namespace,
        )


    import ctypes


    class ctype:  # noqa
        int = _make_ctype_from_ctypes(ctypes.c_int)
        int32 = _make_ctype_from_ctypes(ctypes.c_int32)


    clock = Clock()
    print(clock.ticks)
```

stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wotori\git\L2py\main.py", line 69, in <module>
    print(clock.ticks)
  File "C:\Users\wotori\git\L2py\main.py", line 23, in ticks
    return ctype.int(int(time.time() - self.start_time) / self.MSEC_IN_TICK)
  File "C:\Users\wotori\git\L2py\main.py", line 42, in __init__
    super().__init__(value)
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

should be:
int(0)

Comment: Please make a [mcve]…one code that can be copy/paste/run and produce the error, not snippets that don’t show how the code is run.  That `if 'int'…` looks suspicious if the underlying type is c_long.

Comment: @MarkTolonen look at UPDATE #2. Now you can copy paste to see what I am talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing to fix.  On Windows `ctypes.c_int` and `ctypes.c_int32` are aliases for `ctypes.c_long` because C `int`, `int32_t` and `long` are all the same integer size on Windows.

From the [ctypes documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes-fundamental-data-types-2):

> *class* ctypes.**c_int**
> Represents the C signed int datatype. The constructor accepts an optional integer initializer; no overflow checking is done. On platforms where `sizeof(int) == sizeof(long)` it is an alias to `c_long`.
> ...
> *class* ctypes.**c_int32**
> Represents the C 32-bit signed int datatype. Usually an alias for `c_int`.

**EDIT**

Per code update, on Windows `ctype.int` and `ctype.int32` will both be `<class '__main__.long'>`.  In `_Numeric.__init__()`, `self.__class__.__name__` will be `'long'`.  Change the line:

```
if "int" in self.__class__.__name__:
```

to something like the following and it will work, since all those types need the `value = int(value)` line to change the input `value` from a `float` to an `int`:

```
if self.__class__.__name__ in ('int', 'int32', 'long'):
```

You might also consider making the line an `else:` if the three ifs cover all the bases.

Comment: sounds reasonable, thanks! But for some reason, when executing the same code, I get a working program in one case, and an error in the case of windows

Comment: @WotoriMovako Ask a question about the *actual* code.

Comment: I added more details to the question, @MarkTolonen.